# Firestore instant search skips some results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a ***TextChangeListener*** on edittext and calling a function on ***afterTextChanged()***, which queries the firestore collection("users") for available *usernames* in the collection.

Now the problem is if user types slowly in the edittext then there is no problem. the code works fine. but if users types at very fast, the listener skips some results or the results are not received in the order they are fired and therefor the result with the final username in edittext is not the perfect one. How to resolve this?

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                isUsernameAvailable(s.toString())

            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        })
```

```
private fun isUsernameAvailable(username:String){
   db.collection("users")
            //.orderBy("username")
            .whereEqualTo("username",username)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {documents->
                // showing the result if documents with username available or not.
             }
}
```

Comment: why you don't use the onTextChanged method?

Comment: will this affect?

Comment: By having continuous searches, you're having a lot of read operations on firestore. Read more on how reads are calculated in firestore. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing

Comment: but @VedprakashWagh is there any other solution?

Comment: You can get the result from editText like editText.getText().toString() and then search for the username only once

Comment: but it I want it to be instant search.

Comment: Think about it. You have million users, you put "a", and it returns 10K results. You have not added any bound to your query too, so it'll return 10K users resulting in 10K reads. Atleast add bound/limit to your query then.

Comment: You can do it  this way, get all users in background once when user open the activity or when user launch the app. Then you filter your search from the results of user you got.